# How to GROUP BY hour and take missing hours as 0 in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

I am making `GROUP BY` hour for one day. In this case there are some time intervals with no data. **How can i take these missing hours as 0 value**?. Then there would be always 23 value in my query result.
Below what I tried so far.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), extract(hour from created_date) as hourr 
FROM client_requests 
WHERE created_date > '2020-02-24 00:00:00' and created_date < '2020-02-24 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY extract(hour from created_date) 
ORDER BY extract(hour from created_date) ASC
```

result is like below:

```
count                |     hourr    |
------------------------------------
1                    |      0
1                    |      6
5                    |      8
14                   |      9
35                   |      10
37                   |      11
40                   |      12
32                   |      13
18                   |      14
28                   |      15
39                   |      16
31                   |      17
30                   |      18
16                   |      19
7                    |      20
11                   |      21
14                   |      22
```

But i need like this

```
count                |     hourr    |
------------------------------------
1                    |      0
0                    |      1
0                    |      2
0                    |      3
0                    |      4
0                    |      5
1                    |      6
0                    |      7
5                    |      8
14                   |      9
35                   |      10
37                   |      11
40                   |      12
32                   |      13
18                   |      14
28                   |      15
39                   |      16
31                   |      17
30                   |      18
16                   |      19
7                    |      20
11                   |      21
14                   |      22
0                    |      23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left join with a generated table of hours:

```
SELECT coalesce(count(r.*), 0) AS count,
       h.h as hour
FROM generate_series(0, 23) AS h
   LEFT JOIN client_requests AS r
      ON extract(hour from r.created_date) = h.h
         AND r.created_date >= '2020-02-24 00:00:00'
         AND r.created_date < '2020-02-25 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY h.h
ORDER BY h.h;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it is giving same result as before.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to move the condition into the join clause. Fixed.